# Mixed Content XML parsing using DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, xml-parsing

I have an XML document that has mixed content and I am using a custom schema in Dataframe to parse it.  I am having an issue where the schema will only pick up the text for "Measure".

The XML looks like this

```
<QData>
    <Measure> some text here
        <Answer>Answer1</Answer>
        <Question>Question1</Question>
    </Measure>
    <Measure> some text here
        <Answer>Answer1</Answer>
        <Question>Question1</Question>
    </Meaure>
</QData>
```

My schema is as follows:

```
def getCustomSchema():StructType = {StructField("QData",
      StructType(Array(
        StructField("Measure",
          StructType( Array( 
            StructField("Answer",StringType,true),
            StructField("Question",StringType,true)                
        )),true)
      )),true)}
```

When I try to access the data in Measure I am only getting "some text here" and it fails when I try to get info from Answer. I am also just getting one Measure.

EDIT:  This is how I am trying to access the data

```
val result = sc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("attributePrefix", "attr_").schema(getCustomSchema)
    .load(filename.toString)

val qDfTemp = result.mapPartitions(partition =>{val mapper = new QDMapper();partition.map(row=>{mapper(row)}).flatMap(list=>list)}).toDF()

case class QDMapper(){
    def apply(row: Row):List[QData]={
        val qDList = new ListBuffer[QData]()
        val qualData = row.getAs[Row]("QData") //When I print as list I get the first Measure text and that is it
        val measure = qualData.getAs[Row]("Measure") //This fails
}
}
```

Comment: What is your spark.read command?

Comment: I am using val Qdata = row.getAs[Row]("QData") for the data.  I tried val measure = Qdata.getAs[Row]("Measure") but it fails

Comment: You can try using Databrick's library for reading xml documents as dataframe.

    val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "Measure").load("test.xml")

Comment: That is what I am using but I have created a custom schema for it.  Right before .load("test.xml") I have .schema(getCustomSchema).

Comment: Dear future people.  I have not found a solution to this exact problem. We just added a process to enclose the "some text here" in its own XML tag and the data bricks parser works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

you can use row tag as a root tag and access other element:-

```
df_schema = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='<xml_tag_name>').load(schema_path)
```

please visit https://github.com/harshaltaware/Pyspark/blob/main/Spark-data-parsing/xmlparsing.py for brief code